# How do I delete the left/right padding of row start/end?

Tags: css, bootstrap-4

I have a row of cards of a particular size, with a gutter between them. Problem is, the gutter is also applied on both sides of each card that starts and ends the row. I need both the start and end to align with the border of the parent container. I can't find the right words to query this. The closest I got is someone who generates static grids and adds css for first-child. My grid can theoretically be anywhere from 0-99999999 results. I need the first (left-padding) and last (right-padding) in each row to not have the respective paddings.

### Example code

```html
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="tile in tiles">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img ng-src=" {{ tile.image }} ">
                <p>{{ tile.title }}</p>
           </div>
        </div>  
    </div> 
</div>
```

### Result

```
| [card] [card] [card] |
| [card] [card] [card] |
```

### Desired Result

```
|[card] [card] [card]|
|[card] [card] [card]|
```

Comment: I guess its padding and not margin, you need to set padding:0px for left and right for row class in CSS

Comment: row inside container .. and use container-fluid

Comment: By default, the gutter is 30px between columns, and 15px and either end making it *half* at the start and end. You want the start and end to be 0px?

Comment: @TemaniAfif That doesn't remove the margin-right for the last item in a row, it just changes container behavior.

Comment: @Zim I want the left-margin of the start card and right-margin card on the end of each row of cards (whatever the amount of cards per row may be) to be 0.

Comment: @SonalBorkar You've not understood or read the question properly.

Comment: @RudyvanSloten No you didn't get the answer, card must be inside another container which may have the padding. So you should specify that there was no padding on external container. Later you edited question too.

Comment: @RudyvanSloten -  the spacing (gutter) around columns in Bootstrap is created using *padding*, not margins. That's why saying "delete the margin" is unclear. Also columns should be placed inside `row`, not `container`.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

Adding a margin: 0 -15px 0 -15px; to container was the solution. This is how popular clothing store Zalando tackles this issue.

Comment: @Zim 's answer seems more suitable, using pixels is really bad for the responsivity of the website.

Comment: @AIMEURAmin Zim's answer does not achieve the desired result, so I cannot in good conscience accept it as an answer over the current answer. When someone posts a working answer that is an improvement, I will gladly mark it as such. Furthermore, gutter is a 30px value, so that essentially makes Bootstrap bad for responsivity. The -15 merely counteracts this hardcoded 30px value.

Answer (score 2):

Understand how the grid spacing is created. From the Bootstrap docs:

> "Rows are wrappers for columns. Each column has horizontal padding
>   (called a gutter) for controlling the space between them. This padding
>   is then counteracted on the rows with negative margins..."

Therefore, set container left padding to 0, and then adjust column padding like this...

```
.col-md-4:nth-child(3n) {
    padding-right: 0;
}

@media (max-width:768px) {
    .col-md-4 {
        padding-right: 0;
    }
}
```

Demo: https://www.codeply.com/go/dvPRr13Wev

```
<div class="container pl-0">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-4" ng-repeat="tile in tiles">
            <div class="card mb-4 box-shadow">
                <img src="//placehold.it/500x200">
            </div>
        </div>
        ...
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: No need to play with the nth-child. Setting the gutter as a negative margin on both sides is the fix.

Comment: Then show us and answer your own question. It won't work. It will overflow and cause a horizontal scrollbar, or you'll still have a space in the right.

Comment: If you'll scroll up, you can see that I did, but there is a wait timer on accepting my own answer. And it already works, you can check any product grid view on zalando.nl, which is where I got the code. The left and right side of the parent container (Bootstrap class .container is not browser width) already have a whitespace, because the site is not full width of the browser, unless mobile (in which case the cards stack vertically)

Answer (score 1):

If there are always going to be three cards in a row, you can easily target the first and third card with CSS. However, if you have a container where you can have many cards in the same container with no divider between rows, you have to get a little more tricky with your CSS.

```
// This selector targets every third card starting with the first card.
.card:nth-child(3n-2) {
  margin-left: 0;
}

// This selector targets every third card starting with the third card.
.card:nth-child(3n) {
  margin-right: 0;
}
```

[Here's a good resource explaining the `:nth-child()` pseudo selector in more detail](https://css-tricks.com/almanac/selectors/n/nth-child/).

Comment: it sould be applied to an upper level

Comment: No, the cards per row decrease when the window is thinner.